Disable auto-update of GNOME extensions
I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, GNOME 46.0.
When there are new extensions, the Extensions app shows a little notice at the top:

1 extension will be updated on the next login.    [Log Out...]

This implies an auto-update feature. I don't want that.
It recently auto-updated some extensions which left GNOME in a mess due to extension incompatibility, etc.
How do I disable this "feature"?
UPDATE:
No this is not a duplicate of that linked issue. Firstly that firefox extension is already set to manually update, and secondly and more importantly this is not a problem in my browser. This is independent of the browser and that notification is shown in the Extensions app, not the browser. The auto update occurs in the OS on logout/login, not the browser.

This question is similar to: How do I disable "An update for GNOME Shell extensions" notifications?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I could not find any settings for that.
Here is a dirty workaround by changing the extension UUID, which does work:

install the desired version

cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

change the name of the extension folder

then open the following file and change the UUID field to the new name:
<new_folder_name>/metadata.json

logout, login



Thanks. I don't understand - how would changing the folder's name help?

because gnome will search for update based on the UUID of the extension (identifier). If you change that, then gnome won't find any update. If you change the UUID, you also need to change the folder name

I see. It is a drastic solution, but I'm sure some people will be fine with that. At least you've shown there is a way. Upvoted +1 and thanks.
